# jquery ajax database won't update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

this is my first post on Stackoverflow!

So I'm trying to execute an "Insert" query via Jquery's $.ajax function. Looking at the network tab on chrome dev tools, it seems to be loading my file but not updating the database.

Without any ajax, this code works fine:

```
    <form id="alForm" name="alForm" method="POST" action="add.php">
```

However, this takes me to the blank php page. I don't want that.

Let me share my code!

**Here is the PHP:**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);



$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
try {

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=utility_portal', $user, $pass);


if (isset($_POST['save'])) {


  $t = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `u_links` (`title`, `link`) VALUES (?, ?)");
  $t->execute(array($_POST['title'], $_POST['link']));
   } 

 } catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />" ;
 die();
 }

 ?>
```

**Here is the Jquery:**

```
$('#alForm').on('submit', function(event) {


$.ajax({
    url  : "add.php",
    type : "POST",
    data: $('#alForm').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        alert('submitted ' + data);
    }


});

event.preventDefault();




});
```

**And the HTML:**

```
<form id="alForm" name="alForm">
<label>Title</label>
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title"/>

<label>Link</label>
<input type="text" name="link" placeholder="Link"/>

<input type="submit" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Everything looks fine to me. Am I missing something? Thanks for the help.

Comment: in network tab is correct data being sent? Also does alert trigger?

Comment: Check your web server error logs. PHP errors get logged there. If you have `display_errors` set to off in PHP.ini, even with `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL` you will not see the errors, but they will still be written to the log. Also, parse errors will not display (but will be written to the log) as the error happens during pre-processing before the `error_reporting` line is processed.

Comment: Yes. That's the weird part. The I can see the data from the form in the network tab and the alert does trigger. However, I can't see the data updating in the DB

Comment: try to put `complete` function to get the error from the php into the console if ajax fails.

Comment: I've tried everything I could thing of and googled around for hours. Still no solution. Am I missing a step?

Comment: I took out if(isset($_POST['save'])) { and it worked. Not sure why though, but it's now sending data to DB :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the "serialize" part. If you remove the line the code should work.
You can also use the shortcut code: 
`$.post("add.php",
    success: function(data) {
        alert('submitted ' + data);
    }`